# Are there any TLS approaches in the US? What does a TLS approach plate look like?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, usa, approach

I've been reading about Transponder Landing System (TLS) approaches: https://www.anpc.com/instrument-landing-systems/

What would a TLS approach plate look like? I have ForeFlight and can also get stuff off the FAA website. However, I do not know what airports to look at for approaches. I did try looking at Columbus Gorge Regional Airport (KDLS) as I have seen ANPC saying that airport has their equipment at it.

Does anyone know of any US airport that has a published TLS approach that I can look at for a plate?

Comment: Made a couple changes for grammar and acronym expansion, but have no idea what APNC is.

Comment: https://www.anpc.com/ is Advanced Navigation & Positioning Corporation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a current TLS approach chart.
[image]

Comment: Good find. Not in the U.S., but interesting to find this type of approach in the Antarctica.

Comment: It’s for the US base and is flight checked by the FAA.

Answer (score 9):

In 2011, the only TLS in the US was a test system in Atlantic City:

> The **only civilian TLS in the United States** is a Federal Aviation Administration (FAA) **test system** at the agency’s technical center in **Atlantic City**, New Jersey. However, although the FAA in 1998 certified the TLS as at least meeting ICAO standards for Category I ILS signals and in 2001 granted type acceptance to ANPC’s TLS, the systems are **not likely to be widely used in the United States**.
>
> In recent years, the FAA has instead emphasized the development of instrument approach procedures using the wide area augmentation system (WAAS), a space-based navigation system with a ground-based network of reference stations and master stations that the agency says will not only enhance safety by adding precision-like approach capability but also eliminate the need for installation and maintenance of local airport-based approach equipment.

<sup>([flightsafety.org](https://flightsafety.org/asw-article/new-approach/), emphasis mine)</sup>

I couldn't find any current civilian TLS approach in the US, so most likely none were installed. The approach chart would however look like an ILS chart:

> Pilots fly a TLS approach just as they would an approach using an ILS, ANPC says, so “to the pilot, there is virtually no difference.” For example, **TLS approach charts look like ILS approach charts**; a failure of ground-based equipment to provide lateral or vertical guidance results in a red flag on a cockpit instrument, as it would in an ILS or other instrument approach; and a TLS approach always includes a missed approach procedure — although the TLS itself does not provide missed-approach guidance.

<sup>([flightsafety.org](https://flightsafety.org/asw-article/new-approach/), emphasis mine)</sup>

I found an old picture of the TLS chart at Atlantic City (but I cannot find a current one, maybe it was removed there as well):

[image: TLS RWY 31]
<sup>(image source: [AFMAN11-217v1 on GitBooks](https://johangithub.gitbooks.io/afman11-217v1/content/chp12.html#12_11))</sup>

Answer (score 4):

The FAA does not list "TLS" (**Transponder Landing System**) as part of its inventory of Instrument Approaches: ([FAA Inventory of Instrument Approaches](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/procedures/ifp_inventory_summary/))

However, in a book (at this [website](https://johangithub.gitbooks.io/afman11-217v1/content/chp12.html#12_11)) on the last page of the chapter, figure 12-11, the author shows a TLS instrument approach plate that is highlighted "EXPERIMENTAL for VFR use only not for navigation."  This Instrument Approach plate is for Atlantic City International Airport (ACY).

Also, [FAA Order 8200.47- Flight Inspection of the Transponder Landing System](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/8200.47_Transponder_Landing_System.pdf), dated 09/06/2015,  provides additional information regarding the "TLS" Instrument Approach.

Here is the image of the TLS approach from the book noted above:

[image]